# remove duplicates in set of fields in any row

Tags: knime

Using Knime, I am trying to remove duplicates in all the  rows for set of columns through Groupby node. Can you tell how to implement this or if I can use any other node to get this done.
First I have divided my table in set of columns such as 
set 1 is -->Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
set 2 is-->Col5,col6,Col7,col8
 and like this I have  10 sets(with 4 columns each) now I want to check if there we have same data in any particular set Lets say below values are there in set 1
Col1 has 4
Col2 has 4
Col3 has 4
Col4 has 4

then  I will keep Col1 as 4 and values in Col2, col3,col4 will be 'null' .

Can you please tell me how to do this through GroupBy node in KNIME

I have tried  this using other nodes like constant  Value column Filter, math formula,Rule Engine, but nothing seems to working .

First I have divided my table in set of columns such as 
set 1 is -->Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
set 2 is-->Col5,col6,Col7,col8
 and like this I have  10 sets(with 4 columns each) now I want to check if there we have same data in any particular set Lets say below values are there in set 1
Col1 has 4
Col2 has 4
Col3 has 4
Col4 has 4

then  I will keep Col1 as 4 and values in Col2, col3,col4 will be 'null' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't do it in a GroupBy node. You can get unique values in GroupBy node but you need some logic that will determine that this value is a duplicate and instead of it put null or some other identifier. I advise you to use Rule Engine node with following syntax for last column:

```
$column4$ MATCHES $column1$ OR $column4$ MATCHES $column2$ OR $column4$ MATCHES $column3$ => "null"
TRUE => $column4$
```

After that add two more Rule Engine nodes with syntax for column3 and column2. You don't need to do anything for column1 obviously.

Comment: Thanks  for the answer  ,Is there any other way to reduce the number rule nodes and achieve this in one single  node itself?

Comment: If you only want to use single node you can do it using [Column Expressions](https://hub.knime.com/knime/nodes/Column_Expressions*2_0ji_xeG-SudFu-) node. Multiple rules can be defined there.

Comment: I have one more question-Can you please answer:-


 Since we are using KNIME  to run our    as per our requirement. In our workflows , we  compare customer data in 2 data bases , one oracle and one Hive and then we  want report out  on how much data is matched and how much is not . so now we want to group some customer ids based on locations of the customers to see from which location we are getting more mismatches. Can you tell me which should I use to get this type of customized report.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015025/knime-comparing-datasets/56015823#56015823