# KNIME comparing datasets

Tags: knime

Can you please answer:- Since we are using KNIME to run our as per our requirement. In our workflows , we compare customer data in 2 data bases , one oracle and one Hive and then we want report out on how much data is matched and how much is not . so now we want to group some customer ids based on locations of the customers to see from which location we are getting more mismatches. Can you tell me what all nodes should I use to get this type of customized report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not very clear how you want to do the comparison, but I think you will need the [Joiner](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.preproc.joiner.Joiner2NodeFactory) node. After that you can use the GroupBy node to use the [GroupBy](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.preproc.groupby.GroupByNodeFactory) node to compute the mismatches by location, but before that you should use for example a [Rule Engine](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.rules.engine.RuleEngineNodeFactory) node to convert the missing values created by the **Joiner** to a value (if the original datasets have missing values in the interesting columns, you should change them before the **Joiner**) and all other values to a different value.

Comment: Thanks Gabor , this is really helpful to understand the comparison mechanism , but to replace missing values we do have 'missing value node' available in KNIME, can you tell me if these 2 nodes are for different purposes.

Comment: Rule Engine can do more complex replacements, but if you need to replace only the missing values, the missing value node is a cleaner choice I agree.